# What is the most performant way to write a string to a file?

Tags: c++, string, filestream

I have code which runs lots of loops updating a single string.
Finally I want that string to be stored in a file.

Currently I am printing that string to the console.
I can use a `ofstream` and write that to a file instead of console.

- Instead using a string to be updated, use **directly the file stream**
- Use **string stream** instead and finally **copy that string stream to file**
  stream and write to a file.
- After update of the string is complete I should write a file stream
  at once.

The `std::string::max_size` in my compiler is : 4294967257
And **the maximum size of the string** that I could generate is approximately half of the `max_size` of the compiler.

Note: I am using Solaris Unix.

**What is the most performant way to write this string to a file?**

Comment: It will depend on your environment; OS, free memory, size of the string, how your code update the string...
If size of the string is much smaller than your memory, I think 1st or 2nd is the best.

Comment: How big is the string, how often do you need to write it?

Comment: If performance is you most cared, directly using C file IO is best choice.

Comment: @nihuo: "If performance is you most cared, directly using" a memory mapped file is almost certainly the best choice.  Anyway, drakon's right - it's easy for Vijay to profile his actual app with both implementations and see if it makes any *significant* difference.  Vijay - you might also pay attention to whether the file writing is slow compared to the data generation... if not then you should focus elsewhere.

Comment: The maximum size of the string could be half of the max_size mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one way to know the answer. You have to profile it for your case. You can easily do this by measuring the timings how long it takes to generate the file.

Comment: i tested witha simple for loop and streams. and found that for my case either of 1 or 3 are feasible. but the second one really s****. donno why

Answer (score 0):

Consider all the scenarios and Benchmark the timings.

NOTE : The fastest would be the one closest to the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reuse the same std::string object as much as possible, using reserve and clear. The string will cache its memory allocation. Strings inside {} will make a new allocation each time you enter the block.

Be careful of hidden temporary string objects, for example a + b when a is std::string will create a temporary std::string object with new allocation. Prefer += to concatenate strings.

Use C code to perform conversions. Create a local char buffer and use sprintf etc. They are faster than stringstreams but it's easier to make a mistake so be careful.

Use "\n" instead of std::endl when writing to a file, as the latter causes a flush.

Avoid stringstreams like the plague. They are slow, at least Visual Studio implementation. I've tried them for hardcore text processing and I know.

Of course this assumes performance IS an issue for you. If you are doing light work, stringstreams could be the easiest solution. I prefer them when I am not doing hardcore work as there is much less chance of a bug.